# How to install or upload Autodesk Forge to Cpanel?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

How to install or upload Autodesk Forge to Cpanel ?

i followed the tutorial https://tutorials.autodesk.io/ and it runs fine on localhost. and I have a problem when uploading or installing in Cpanel

Answer (score 0):

For that you would need to refer to cpanel documentation. For example, here's an article for Node.js apps: https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/.

However, if you're getting started with web development, I'd suggest that you use one of the more modern (and more importantly, easier) hosting options such as https://fly.io or https://render.com.